# Definition of a Frenet curve

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Recently I followed a course in Differential Geometry. The book we use is *Differential Geometry: Curves - Surfaces - Manifolds* by Wolfgang Kühnel. My question is about the definition of a Frenet curve.

> **2.4. Definition** (Frenet curve). Let $c(s)$ be a *regular curve* in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is parametrized by arc length and $n$-times continuously differentiable. Then $c$ is called a *Frenet curve*, if at every point the vectors $c',c'',\dots,c^{(n-1)}$ are linearly independent. The *Frenet $n$-frame* $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ is then uniquely determined by the following conditions:
>
> (i) $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are orthonormal and positively oriented.
>
> (ii) For every $k=1,\dots,n-1$ one has $\text{Span}(e_1,\dots,e_k)=\text{Span}(c',\dots,c^{(k)})$.
>
> (iii) $\langle c^{(k)},e_k\rangle>0$ for $k=1,\dots,n-1$.

**My thought:** In this definition, I think (i) and (ii) are enough to uniquely determined $e_1,\dots,e_n$. Indeed, one obtains $e_1,\dots,e_{n-1}$ from $c',\dots,c^{(n-1)}$ by means of the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure, and the missing $e_n$ is then uniquely determined by condition (i). Why condition (iii) is necessary?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you do not assume III you can change $e_j$ to $-e_j$ for an even number of elements and the frame will still satisfy I and II.

Comment: Thanks. I have mistaken that $(e_1,\dots,e_k)$ should be positively oriented for any $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condition (iii) is required in order to ensure that the initial $n-1$ vectors have the same directions.

If you don’t impose it you could have for example $e_1=-\frac{c^\prime}{\Vert c^\prime\Vert}$ and therefore the Frenet $n$-frame « running » in the opposite direction of the one of the tangent of the curve.

Comment: @user1551 I’m only speaking of the first vector here, showing that without third condition, the first vector can be chosen in the opposite direction of the tangent... which is not what Frenet $n$-frame is desired.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you meant now.